# Nightwatch SWC core error when running a test

Tags: node.js, swc, nightwatch

After using the Nightwatch installer to add Nightwatch to my existing folder, I encountered an error while running the sample tests.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling 'swc' and even updated it to the latest version, but the issue still persists.

I'd really appreciate any assistance with this problem.

Comment: please add the steps you have taken to add Nightwatch and the errors you got in the question.